# In Jquery Mobile Dropdown Popup UI distorts when Orientation change from portrait to landscape or vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

When I am rotating device from portrait to landscape or vice versa then dropdown popup UI goes to Upper left corner. ScreenShots are also attached. Can you please look into that. Any suggestion or solution would be great help. Below is the code:

> ```
> <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
>     <option value="1">Veni</option>
>     <option value="2">Vedi</option>
>     <option value="3">Vici</option>
> </select>
> ```

[image: Portrait Orientation]

[image: Landscape Orientation]